# apache2 virtualhost .htaccess file doesnt seem to work

Tags: server, apache2, lamp, wordpress, apache2.4

I cant get my .htaccess file to work correctly.

In my `apache2.conf` file I have the following.

```
<Directory /home/felix/mysite>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But this does not change anything. I still get a 404 error when trying to reach different pages on my website.

EDIT more info:

Ubuntu 16.04

Apache 2.4

Inside my sites `sites-available` I have my `mysite.se.conf` file which looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/felix/mysite
    ServerName mysite.se
    ServerAlias www.mysite.se

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried removing this part from apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /home/felix/mysite>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And got this message now `You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe`.

I get this message now even when I added that part back.

The site which I am trying to get to work is built with wordpress. Inside the root folder of this site I have an .htaccess file which looks like this:

```
# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
# End Error

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ReewriteEngine On
eRewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The thing is that these settings works on another Ubuntu machine. And the server administartor could not find the error in mine. So he said that is probobly a some faults in the apache2 configuration. But I cant locate it, everything seems to be as it should.

I think this could be at fault: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/wordpress-permalinks-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04

specifically: `Also make sure your .htaccess file has the proper permissions for WP to write to it. You'll see an error if it doesn't.`

How can I change it to right permission?

SOLUTION:

I am sorry that I cant give a better solution. But all I did was `sudo a2enmod rewrite` then `sudo service apache2 restart`. First time I did this I got an error (500 server error or a 403 permission error, cant remember) but tried it again this morning and it worked. So my files still looks as the above.

Comment: To be able to help, we will need more information. I do not think it is an .htaccess file problem, and for some initial testing I suggest you delete it so as to first get things working without any .htaccess. We also need to see whatever you did for your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/?` file.

Comment: Alright, sorry! Will edit my post!

Comment: @DougSmythies Please see edit!

Answer (score 2):

Try to edit `mysite.se.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/felix/job/fello
    ServerName test.fello.se
    ServerAlias www.test.fello.se
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory "/home/felix/job/fello">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And check path to you site `/home/felix/mysite` or `/home/felix/job/fello` ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55070/discussion-on-answer-by-tagplus5-apache2-virtualhost-htaccess-file-doesnt-seem).